# Bounding the infinity norm using the l_2 norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Suppose $\Big(\sum_{k =1}^n x_k^2\Big)^{1/2} \leq \eta_2$.

$\eta_2$ is the bound on the l_2 norm of a matrix.
I want to upper bound $\eta_\infty = \max_{i}|x_i|$ using $\eta_2$ the bound on the l_2 norm of the matrix.

Is there a standard approach to do this?

Comment: Defining all the quantities in the question would be helpful.

Comment: made the formula simpler to reflect my question. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $i$, $x_i^{2} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{2}$ so  $|x_i| \leq \sqrt {\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{2}} \leq \eta_2$. Taking sup over $i$ you get $\eta_{\infty} \leq \eta_2$.

Comment: what is $a^2_k$? Is this bound correct if its an integration instead of sum?

Comment: Sorry, I typed $a_k$ for $x_k$. I have corrected it now. The inequality fails for integrals. For example, if $f(x)=x$ in $(0,1)$ then $\max f(x)=1$ and $\int_0^{1} f^{2}(x) \, dx =\frac 1 3$.

Comment: You mean $\left(\int_0^1 f(x)^2\,dx\right)^{1/2}$?

Comment: Sorry again. Corrected my comment.

Comment: LOL, as did I. :)

Comment: Thanks. I have another related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947814/bounding-a-sup-in-a-continuos-space-using-the-l-infinity-norm. Do you have any ideas?